# What is the folder add in rxjs 5 for?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

When looking through the rxjs directory structure, there seems to be two copies of the ***observable*** and ***operator*** folders - one inside the `add` folder as well as outside [add](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/add).

Can someone explain why those two copies exist?

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of how it's used or are you asking only why a particular directory structure was chosen?

Comment: the later, but if you know both you are free to add that as part of your answer as well

Answer (score 2):

The two sets of directories serve slightly different purposes. The actual source for the instance and class operators are stored in the `operator` and `observable` folders that exist outside the `add` folder. So, for eg, when you use stream$.map, the javascript code for that `map` operator will exist in the *non-add* operator folder.

By default, RxJS comes with a ton of instance and class operators to do a whole bunch of things. Most users of the library, however, will only use a fraction of those operators. Thus, through using the right import, RxJS allows for you to create your Observable class without any operators at all, and then add only those operators that you want to use to the Observable type.

That second use case is the reason for the `add` folder.

So, for eg, you can:

```
// get the basic Observable type with no operators added at all
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; 

// add the map instance operator so you can do observableInstance.map
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  

// add the Observable.of class operator so you can do Observable.of
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

If you look at the source code for anything in that `add` folder, you see it delegates most of the work to the `non-add` versions - it just patches the base Observable type to add the operator in question.

**All the credit to @Eye on this:**

Why do we bother to split the code out this way? It's done done primarily for client side code's efficiency, specifically to reduce the size of the code that must be sent from the server to the browser. So, instead of importing the entire library with tons of code you will not use, you just import the code observables/observers as well as operators that you need. When doing so the client side bundle size will drastically reduce.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 this is done primarily for client side code's efficiency, particularly to reduce the size of imported library when bundled with Webpack. So, instead of importing the entire library with tons of code you will not use, you just import the code observables/observers as well as operators that you need. When doing so the client side bundle size will drastically reduce.